# Color Management 2 monitors on Ubuntu Studio 16.04 with Spyder5 express

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-studio, color-management, multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntustudio 16.04 with 2 Dell ultrasharp monitors (same model)  with Spyder5 express. Xubuntu which it is base upon doesn't have colour management for one thing. Where I am really lost is I have more than one monitor being driven by a Nvidia K4000. The colours in One monitor are different that the other.
How do I calibrate the two monitors independently ?